# How to reload a screen when I receive a remote notification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-fcm

I am using RN 0.54 with react-navigation having 3 tabs - tanks, alerts, and settings. I want to navigate and reload the alerts tab whenever I receive a notification for alerts.

I am able to navigate to the alerts screen when I am in either tanks or settings tab but when I get a notification while I'm in the alerts tab, nothing happens.

Now I want to reload the alerts screen while I'm on the alerts screen when I receive a notification.

Any lead would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the React philosophy, reloading screens shouldn't be done.

In my opinion, what you can do is, you place all your alerts in a state and use `setState({})` whenever a notification arises. This way, you can refresh your alert screen without reloading the screen.

**EDIT**

Adding to the answer, it can still be achieved via states.

A primary state can be maintained. For example `isReloaded: false:`

Whenever a notification comes, `setState({isReloaded: true})` and in your `render()` method you can call a function which fetches you new data and updates the state accordingly (you'll have to do a `this.state.isReloaded = false` inside this function, to enable it to be called again).

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned this in the question. I have a flatlist in alert screen. What i meant by reload is calling a fetch and updating my state with new data. i want to perform this action when i receive a new alert notification.

Comment: let me give it a try.